# A clean minimal gem to add a simple blog to existing app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, blogs

I need an blog inside my existing app but it doesn't have to be fancy, some category's and an way to convert a directory of textiles to the blogposts including date would fit, already searched for this but nothing fancy came up.

any recommendations on a good gem to add blog to existing rails app?

Comment: Rails seems to be built **exactly** for making blogs. At least, that's what I see in all tutorials. :) So, it should take you no more than couple of hours to roll your own simple implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally ended up with a very simple blog controller that loads some page content from the database, using [redcloth](http://redcloth.org/) to preserve formatting, also use this same method for serving static pages in my app.

Answer (score 19):

You can roll out your own simple blogging engine for your needs and Rails makes it easy. However, there are a couple of options which work fantastically:

1. [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) ( Checkout [Jekyll Bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) as well)
2. [Typo](https://github.com/publify/publify)

There are other full blown CMS solutions available:

1. [Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/)
2. [Refinery CMS](http://refinerycms.com/)
3. [Locomotive](http://locomotivecms.com/)

Comment: I don't really like any of these. Jekyll, too time consuming and not user friendly (for non-technical users) as it requires markdown and must be pushed to the server. Locomotive is a pain to deal with and has terrible documentation and support. Refinery uses a lot of outdated items and is too opionated. But I will look into Typo.